# Note attributes in InventoryItem DAC

Tags: acumatica

I was writing a routine that required several fields from the InventoryItem DAC and I noticed all the attributes on the NoteID field. I know the [PXNote] attribute carries all the properties for the note field and methods, but what does the [PXSearchable] attribute do?

```
#region NoteID
public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
protected Guid? _NoteID;
[PXSearchable(SearchCategory.IN, "{0}: {1}", 
 new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.itemType), typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD) },
 new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.descr) }, 
 NumberFields = new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD) },
 Line1Format = "{0}{1}{2}", 
 Line1Fields = new Type[] { typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD),
                            typeof(INItemClass.descr), 
                            typeof(InventoryItem.baseUnit) },
 Line2Format = "{0}", 
 Line2Fields = new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.descr) },
 WhereConstraint = typeof(Where<Current<InventoryItem.itemStatus>, 
                             NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>>)
)]
[PXNote]
public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PXSearchableAttribute` is used for including specified fields of the records in the  Acumatica's Full-Text Entity Index. It allows you searching that fields values in the top-left search-box(Modern UI).